# mongodb filter documents with longitude,latitude and with particular distance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My schema design:

```
var LocationSchema = new Schema({
  area: String,
  loc: [
    type: [Number],  // [<longitude>, <latitude>]
    index: '2d'      // create the geospatial index
    ]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Location', LocationSchema);
```

Data has stored like this mongodb

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58c2796d734d1d46588666c6"
    },
    "area": "madiwla",
    "loc": [
        12.9226,
        77.6174
    ]
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58c27989734d1d4658866705"
    },
    "area": "majestic",
    "loc": [
        12.9767,
        77.5713
    ]
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58ca1e21734d1d2ca8566f3c"
    },
    "area": "shanthi nagar",
    "loc": [
        12.8486,
        77.6837
    ]
}
```

after that i have done

```
db.locations.ensureIndex({loc:"2d"})
```

now i want to filter data within  2km or 5m
i tired this query but every evry times query returns all the documents

i have run 1km max distance query

```
db.locations.find({ loc : { $near : [12.9592,77.6974] , $maxDistance : 100/111.12 } } )
```

i given marathahalli latitude  and longitude

marathahalli  to madiwala distance :- 13.4 km

marathahalli  to majestic distance :- 20.4 km

marathahalli  to shanthi nagar distance :- 23.4 km

but why my query returns all the documnents .IS there any mistake in my code please help me out?

i tried this also but got error

```
db.locations.find({ loc : {
  $near: {
     $geometry: {
          loc: [12.9592,77.6974]
     },
     $maxDistance:0,
     $minDistance:250
  }
} } )

Error: error: {
        "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "invalid point in geo near query $geometry argument: { loc: [
 12.9592, 77.6974 ] }  Point must be an array or object",
        "code" : 2
}
```

i have tried in  mongoshell but i am not getting anything

```
db.locations.createIndex({loc:"2dsphere"})
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 3,
        "numIndexesAfter" : 3,
        "note" : "all indexes already exist",
        "ok" : 1
}
rs-ds161028:PRIMARY> db.locations.aggregate([ {$geoNear: { near :{type
 "Point", coordinates:[77.6974,12.9591]}, distanceField: "distance", spherical:
true } } ])

{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c27989734d1d4658866705"), "area" : "majestic", "loc" : [
2.9767, 77.5713 ], "distance" : 8017976.609884486 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c2796d734d1d46588666c6"), "area" : "madiwla", "loc" : [ 1
.9226, 77.6174 ], "distance" : 8021105.860532911 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ca1e21734d1d2ca8566f3c"), "area" : "shanthi nagar", "loc"
: [ 12.8486, 77.6837 ], "distance" : 8025509.538529409 }

rs-ds161028:PRIMARY>  db.locations.find({ loc:{ $near:{ $geometry: {ty
e: "Point" , coordinates:[77.6974,12.9591] }, $maxDistance:10000 }}})
rs-ds161028:PRIMARY>
```

Comment: Write your mongo geo query.

Comment: can you help me out @VaibhavPatil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before starting i would add two points-

1. When using mongo, always insert locations in [long., lat.] manner
2. Please specify type of geometry you are inserting. Refer mongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/) for more info on types.

Coming to your query, I added three points as your question and my data looks like below-

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : "madiwala", "type" : "Point", "loc" : [ 77.6174, 12.9226 ] }
{ "_id" : "Majestic", "type" : "Point", "loc" : [ 77.5712, 12.9766 ] }
{ "_id" : "ShanthiNgr", "type" : "Point", "loc" : [ 77.6836, 12.8486 ] }
```

I have given type: "Point" because this is a reserved key for using spherical type locations in mongo. Moreover I have added [long, lat] for location.
Later I added a 2dSphere index on loc field.

```
db.test.createIndex({loc:"2dsphere"})
```

Then I executed below query to know the distance from Marathahalli [77.6974,12
.9591]-

```
> db.test.aggregate([ {$geoNear: { near :{type: "Point", coordinates:[77.6974,12
.9591]}, distanceField: "distance", spherical: true } } ])
{ "_id" : "madiwala", "type" : "Point", "loc" : [ 77.6174, 12.9226 ], "distance": 9583.305405402776 }
{ "_id" : "ShanthiNgr", "type" : "Point", "loc" : [ 77.6836, 12.8486 ], "distance" : 12391.53898270671 }
{ "_id" : "Majestic", "type" : "Point", "loc" : [ 77.5712, 12.9766 ], "distance": 13828.057829128267 }
```

Above query is just for testing purpose to know the distance. It tells distance in meters so i can easily convert it into kms.

Now I did run below query to find locations from Marathahalli within 10 kms. distance and i got my desired result-

```
> db.test.find({ loc:{ $near:{ $geometry: {type: "Point" , coordinates:[77.6974,12.9591] }, $maxDistance:10000 }}})
{ "_id" : "madiwala", "type" : "Point", "loc" : [ 77.6174, 12.9226 ] }
```

I found few issues with approach you were trying-

- Locations has to be given in [long, lat] manner.
- type:"Point" has to be given for using point type location. It is reserved keyword.
- Distance will be taken in meters here. At few places it is taken in radian as well in Mongo. Please refer [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/) mongoDB doc for more info on radian distance.

Hope it helps you...have a good day...:)

Comment: can you pls add Schema design so that it will be helpful for me

Comment: I didn't use any specific software to do this. I just used mongo shell. As you can see in my answer, the document looks like {"_id" : <area name>, "type" : "Point", "loc" : [ < long., lat >]}. I agree that this is not the document which you have taken but I think you pasted the document from some aggregation stage or using some other framework because mongo shell doesn't recognize $oid in your code. Hope you can later my document design as per your need. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: i also use mongoshell only but its not working can you please add schema design

Comment: I didnot use any schema thing. I just went into test collection and inserted these three docs. I don't know much about schema you are talking about. I think mongo is schema less and it is not mandatory to follow a schema here....

Comment: send me what is the exact data u r used

Comment: I opened my mongo shell...Inserted the three docs using command db.test.insertMany([{ "_id" : "madiwala", "type" : "Point", "loc" : [ 77.6174, 12.9226 ] },
{ "_id" : "Majestic", "type" : "Point", "loc" : [ 77.5712, 12.9766 ] },
{ "_id" : "ShanthiNgr", "type" : "Point", "loc" : [ 77.6836, 12.8486 ] }]) then i created index using command db.test.createIndex({loc:"2dsphere"}) and then i executed the query db.test.find({ loc:{ $near:{ $geometry: {type: "Point" , coordinates:[77.6974,12.9591] }, $maxDistance:10000 }}}) to get the points near given location within 10 kms.

Comment: i need one more help if i want to filter only madiwla

Comment: If you look closely then madiwala distance is 9583.305405402776 i.e. ~9.5 kms so if you keep maxdistance as 10 kms then you will get only madiwala. If you just want madiwala without any distance thing then db.test.find({_id:"madiwala"}) will also help, i hope that is not what you want.