# I couldn't able to fetch the records by using latitude and longitude, using Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to fetch the records based on latitude and longitude using mongodb. I've gone through many examples nothing worked out for me.

Here is my Schema structue.

```
latlang: {
  type: { type: String, default: 'Point'},
  coordinates: [Number]
}
```

After storing the values it is looking like

```
latlang:{
  type: "Point",
  coordinates: [77.6836, 12.8486]
}
```

I'm setting index for the latlang field like

```
schema.index({ 'latlang.coordinates' : '2dsphere' });
```

I've multiple records like as below

```
latlang:{
  type: "Point",
  coordinates: [77.6836, 12.8486]
}

latlang:{
  type: "Point",
  coordinates: [77.5712, 12.9766]
} 

 latlang:{
  type: "Point",
  coordinates: [77.6174, 12.9226]
}
```

when i'm tring to fetch the records with the below query i'm getting null response

```
User.find({ loc:{ $near:{ $geometry: {type: "Point" , coordinates:[77.6974,12.9591] }, $maxDistance:10000 }}}).exec();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You defined a `latlang` index and schema but in your query you are filtering for a `loc` field. I think this could be a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Create index for latlang: 
 `db.<schema>.createIndex({"latlang":"2dsphere"});`

then make a query like

```
User.find({
latlang: {
    $near: {
        $geometry: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: coords
        },
        $maxDistance: 10000
    }
}
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `latlang ` will not accept there, that must be a `loc` @srikar jammi

Comment: Finally i achieved with this reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826320/mongodb-filter-documents-with-longitude-latitude-and-with-particular-distance